# Wireless network AND dhcp wired server

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, dhcp

I have an ubuntu server, which automatically connects to a wireless network on startup. This is achieved through `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
pre-up wpa_supplicant [...]
post-down sudo killall [...]
```

However, I would like the machine to act also as a dhcp server when somebody plugs in a cable. I installed `dhcp3-server`, and then configured `/etc/network/interfaces` by adding:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.0.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 10.0.0.0/25
  gateway 10.0.0.1
```

However, Internet is now unreachable, as the machine tries (me thinks) to connect through eth0 rather than wlan0.

*How do I configure a machine to have both wireless internet access, and acting as a wired dhcp server?*

EDIT: attached requested output.

`ifconfig -a`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [...]  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          [...]

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [...]  
          inet addr:10.7.0.213  Bcast:10.7.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:bfff:fe36:cea7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1368 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:66 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:267437 (267.4 KB)  TX bytes:9606 (9.6 KB)
```

`rounte -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.7.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: please add the result of `ifconfig -a` and `route -n` it will hel us UNDERSTAND THE PROBLEM;

Comment: sorry for the capital letters, it's a mistake not a shout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try

```
route del default gw 10.0.0.1
route add default gw 10.7.0.1
```

It will use your old gw as your new default gateway.
Those settings will be reset after a reboot.

Comment: This works! I have to work out how to automate that however. Thank you.